# Administrator role missing

Tags: users

I have installed Drupal 8.6.3 minimum profile and found out that there's no Administrator role under permissions section. Is this normal or am I missing something?

We have few people that needs to be using Admin roles, so without a Administrator role, I can't assign them to such a role.

[image]

Comment: @see [Document difference between "standard" and "minimal" core install profiles](https://www.drupal.org/project/documentation/issues/892348) which I found after googling for: drupal minimal profile administrator role.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @leymannx
Can't I just create the Administrator role without reinstalling a standard profile as I have already in the middle of the project?

Comment: I'd say so. But better try it out yourself. Dump your current database. Then try it out. If it's not working as expected drop the database and reimport the previously dumped database.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, that is expected, since the *Minimal* profile creates less entities than the *Standard* profile. You can see that by comparing the [config/install](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/profiles/minimal/config/install?h=8.7.x) directory in the first profile with the [config/install](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/profiles/standard/config/install?h=8.7.x) directory in the latter profile.

As per creating the role from the user interface, that would be possible, but the created role would be a role like the others, while the *Administrator* role created from the *Standard* profile automatically gets all the permissions defined in a Drupal site. In fact, [`Role::hasPermission()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21Role.php/function/Role%3A%3AhasPermission/8.7.x) uses the following code.

```
  if ($this->isAdmin()) {
    return TRUE;
  }
  return in_array($permission, $this->permissions);
```

For the *Administrator* role, `$this->isAdmin()` always return `TRUE`; for every role you create from the user interface, `$this->isAdmin()` would return `FALSE`.

If you need that role, and you cannot reinstall Drupal using the *Standard* profile, you can create a custom module, for which you create a config/optional/user.role.administrator.yml file with the following content.

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - yourmodule
id: administrator
label: Administrator
weight: 2
is_admin: true
permissions: {  }
```

(Replace *yourmodule* with the module name.)

When the module is installed, the role will be created. Since the file contains `is_admin: true`, the role will have all the permissions, automatically, like the *Administrator* role created by the *Standard* profile.

The alternative method that doesn't involve writing modules is importing the [user.role.administrator.yml](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/blob/8.7.x/core/profiles/standard/config/install/user.role.administrator.yml) file in the site. The content of the file is similar to the content of the file I previously suggested, with the exception that there aren't dependencies.

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: administrator
label: Administrator
weight: 2
is_admin: true
permissions: {  }
```

I would use the custom module method if there are other entities/bundles that you normally create when installing Drupal for a new site.
If instead you don't have the need to create other entities/bundles, importing a single file is quicker.

If you installed Drush, with `drush config-edit user.role.administrator` you can edit that file and set `is_admin` to `true`.

Comment: Very profound answer. Another option to create the role would be to import the YAML code in UI here: admin/config/development/configuration/single/import

Comment: What about: drush role-create 'administrator' 'Administrator'

Comment: @rebeling I am not sure it works, if `role-create` doesn't have a flag that sets `is_admin` to `TRUE`. The role name doesn't have a particular meaning; otherwise, Drupal 8 won't use `is_admin`.

Comment: ha, just changed the yaml for this role is_admin from *null* to *true* and imported the config ...the role is_admin now. thx

Comment: Thanks @rebeling, I found the yaml config in `web/core/profiles/standard/config/install/user.role.administrator.yml` and imported it. Worked perfect. @klamlaluno, I'd suggest adding that method to your answer. :)

Comment: The last part in your answer you can achieve by directly editing the config with `drush config-edit user.role.administrator` and setting `is_admin` to `true`.

Comment: Great answer! This difference between the installation profiles is pretty dumb, even by Drupal standards.